# How can I use API to get quickbooks data without browser based OAUTH?

Tags: php, api, oauth, quickbooks

This is in relation to the online version of Quickbooks, QBO (not the desktop).

We need our serverside code to be able to log-in and query some data from quickbooks (just like your API provides) and supply this information to our billing system. This would not involved a browser and use something like curl but this means there is no browser and no human to 'log in' and 'request access' each time. I have not found a way to do this yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question was already answered over here:

- https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/767273-how-can-i-use-api-to-get-quickbooks-data-without-browser-based-oauth

Alas, for the sake of verboseness:

No matter which API you choose, you can do what you're asking.

Regardless of which API you go with (qbXML, or Intuit Anywhere/OAuth) you only need a human to get things connected *the very first time you connect*.

After that very first time, you can fetch data at any time you want (as you suggest, with CURL) with zero interaction with an actual user. All you have to do is store the OAuth credentials that Intuit gives you. This is how all OAuth implementations work - you store the credentials you get back, so you can request data unattended later.

If that's not the behavior you're seeing, it just means you've implemented something incorrectly (and should probably post your code, so we can help you troubleshoot).

You might want to check out the [QuickBooks PHP DevKit](http://consolibyte.com/quickbooks-open-source/), which has examples of doing just what you're asking for:

- http://consolibyte.com/quickbooks-open-source/

Comment: Thanks and you are correct, I just interpreted the unauthorized issues I am encountering to be due to a limitation. Now I created another post-issue as I have narrowed down the issue further.

Answer (score 1):

Best approach is to generate the access token and the refresh token manually via the Quickbooks OAuth playground https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/playground, save these values and then refresh token every hour.

This process however need to be repeated every 101 days because of refresh token expiry.