# quickbooks apis without a browser

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

**Primary question:**

Is there any (supported/non-hacky) way to use Quickbooks Online and Customer Account Data APIs without involving a browser at all, i.e. making an API request from a server?

**Commentary:**

The IPP docs only mention saml and 3-legged oauth, which seems to imply that any authentication and subsequent api calls must come from a browser.

Note that this is *not* satisfactorily answered by this:

[How can I use API to get quickbooks data without browser based OAUTH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219015/how-can-i-use-api-to-get-quickbooks-data-without-browser-based-oauth)

, as that answer:

1. is not by Intuit and does not point to an Intuit source
2. suggests a hacky solution: a user/browser authenticates, after which the oauth/etc. credentials are stored and reused. This seems like a particularly bad idea for long-term use unless explicitly approved by Intuit, due to the fact that the apis may (and probably will) expire any oauth/saml tokens at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, to get accessToken and accessSecret you need to use a browser.

As you have mentioned, your 2nd option is the only way to achieve this. i.e reusing stored tokens.

PN - OAuth tokens are valid for 180 days. Before the token expires, your app can obtain a new token to provide uninterrupted service by calling the Reconnect API. You can automate this part by writing a small program which will call ReconnectAPI when tokens are older than 150 days.

Ref - [Manage OAuth Tokens](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0020_connect/0010_from_within_your_app#Manage_OAuth_Access_Tokens)

You can generate OAuth tokens(for the very first time) from here - [IPP OAuth Playground](https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA)

**CAD**
Here, OAuth tokens are valid for 1 hour.  After an hour, your application will have to issue another SAML assertion again to request a new OAuth token to use. The token should only be persisted during your user's session, and then destroyed.

Ref - [CAD SAML](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/009_using_customeraccountdata/0010_gettingstarted/0025_making_your_first_connection#Send_a_SAML_Assertion_to_the_Intuit_OAuth_Server)

Thanks

Comment: awesome, thanks for the clear answer and references.